# How to transmit of stream of data to multiple devices using sockets in Android?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to transmit a continuous stream of data to multiple devices over a `portable hotspot connection` using `sockets`.

I am facing two **problems**:

1. The message only gets displayed to the client AFTER all the messages are displayed in `msg` TextView on the server end. So if I use an infinite `while(true)` loop instead of `for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)`, in ServerSocketReplyThread, the message never gets transmitted, and the client eventually crashes
2. I am unable to connect another client to the server until all the messages have been transmitted to the first client.

How do I structure the code to ensure simultaneous, real-time transmission to multiple clients?

Here's what the code looks like:
I am using an activity called Transmit activity, where I am instantiating the `msg` Textview, which replays the sent messages, and a server object.

```
msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.server_replayed_messages);
Server server = new Server(this);
```

The Server class is as follows:

```
public class Server {
TransmitActivity activity;
ServerSocket serverSocket;
String message = "";
static final int socketServerPORT = 8080;
ArrayList<Socket> socketList = new ArrayList<Socket>();

public Server(TransmitActivity a) {
    this.activity = a;
    Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
    socketServerThread.start();
}

public int getPort() {
    return socketServerPORT;
}

public void onDestroy() {
    if (serverSocket != null) {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // create ServerSocket using specified port
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketServerPORT);

            while (true) {
                // block the call until connection is created and return
                // Socket object
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                count++;
                message += "#" + count + " from "
                        + socket.getInetAddress() + ":"
                        + socket.getPort() + "\n";

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        activity.msg.setText(message);
                    }
                });

                SocketServerReplyThread socketServerReplyThread =
                        new SocketServerReplyThread(socket, count);
                socketServerReplyThread.run();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class SocketServerReplyThread extends Thread {

    private Socket hostThreadSocket;
    int cnt;

    SocketServerReplyThread(Socket socket, int c) {
        hostThreadSocket = socket;
        cnt = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        OutputStream outputStream;

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {               
            String msgReply = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

            try {
                outputStream = hostThreadSocket.getOutputStream();
                PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
                printStream.print(msgReply);
                printStream.flush();

                message += "replayed: " + msgReply + "\n";

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        activity.msg.setText(message);
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                message += "Something wrong in SocketServerReplyThread! " + e.toString() + "\n";
            }

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    activity.msg.setText(message);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
}
```

On the client side I have a ReceiveActivity, where I am using the following code when a "Connect" button is clicked:

```
Client myClient = new Client(editTextAddress.getText()
                    .toString(), Integer.parseInt(editTextPort
                    .getText().toString()), response);
myClient.execute();
```

The Client class is as follows:

```
public class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

String dstAddress;
int dstPort;
String response = "";
TextView textResponse;

Client(String addr, int port, TextView textResponse) {
    dstAddress = addr;
    dstPort = port;
    this.textResponse = textResponse;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    Socket socket = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int bytesRead;
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

        /*
         * notice: inputStream.read() will block if no data return
         */
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    textResponse.setText(response);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would guess that the fault is with your client, as you do not break the loop until you detect an EOS.  Maybe your server and client should agree on some other way to notify the end of a message.

Comment: Thanks, @ScaryWombat, that makes sense. Will check that out.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, issues solved. Thanks for that little nudge in the right direction :)